# AngularJS Directive not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm going through the codecademy.com AngularJS course and have gotten stuck on the Bolt Network 2 project. I've narrowed the issue down to that for some reason when Angular run it does not insert html/js for the directive program-listing. I have dumped the code on github here: https://github.com/MichaelLeeHobbs/boltnetwork2

I have gone over ever line at least a 3-4 times and have compared it very closely to the App Market project. Whatever mistake I have made I cannot find it. :( On a side not what tools would you use to debug this? Chrome Dev Tools are not showing any errors :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change:

```
app.directive('program-listing', function() {
```

to:

```
app.directive('programListing', function() {
```

Angular changes the name internally. So you will name your directive cammel cased and use hyphens on the html